# Why is UI testing at the top of the test pyramid?

Tags: selenium, user-interface, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

I've been asked by an interviewer the following questions about the diagram below:

1. Why should less effort be required for UI testing?
2. Is the test pyramid meant for programmers or testers?

Thanks for your help on these questions.

[image]

Comment: I think that the real answer is that someone is over-interpreting that diagram.  And I don't think there is a correct answer to either of those questions.

Comment: Im seeking public opinion about this. There is no right or wrong.

Comment: Opinon-based questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for 1. is that it does not mean "less effort" should be put into UI testing, but that "less code should be covered" by UI testing than the larger portions.

As for 2., it should by considered by anybody who is testing the code.  In some organizations that is (and should be) most often a specialized tester and in others, a developer.

My impression is that these are not very good questions, but I do not mention this during the interview.

Comment: This questions is ask by developer and not from testing background.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Test Pyramid: the key to good automated test strategy](https://medium.com/@timothy.cochran/test-pyramid-the-key-to-good-automated-test-strategy-9f3d7e3c02d5) the following diagram represents the **Test Pyramid** which was originally reflected in one of Martin Fowler's [article](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) which was based on a concept developed by Mike Coen.

---

### Test Pyramid

[image: TestPyramid]

The test pyramid is a tool to fix the problem of over-reliance on long-running *Automated* / *Manual* **UI tests**.

---

### Take aways from the TestPyramid

The pyramid implies that:

- *Tests* on the lower levels are cheaper to write and maintain, and quicker to run.
- *Tests* on the upper levels are more expensive to write and maintain, and slower to run.
- Ideally, you should have **lots** of *unit tests*, **some** *service tests*, and **very few** *UI tests*.

This concept is exactly the reverse case of the **Testing Ice Cream Cone** which is the most often found *Test Strategy* followed across the software industry where we have **very few** *unit tests*, **some** *UI test*, **lots** of *QA tests* and **lots** of *Manual Tests*.

---

### Testing Ice Cream Cone

[image: Testing Ice Cream Cone]

The **Testing Ice Cream Cone** approach can be easily identified where the QA department has created an automated test suite, but the development team has not. As a result, tests will be very long running and flakey because the development team has not helped build the suite or architect the application in a way that makes it easy to test. The new check-ins by the developers breaks the product functionality regularly and they are relying on the QA department to report the defects to fix it up.